# How to pull string value in url using scala regex?

Tags: regex, scala

I have below urls in my applications, I want to take one of the value in urls.
For example:

> rapidvie value 416
>   Input URL: http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/?rapidView=416&projectKey=DSCI&view=detail&
>   Output should be: 416

I've written the code in scala using import java.util.regex.{Matcher, Pattern}

```
val p: Pattern = Pattern.compile("[?&]rapidView=(\\d+)[?&]")**strong text**
        val m:Matcher = p.matcher(url)
        if(m.find())
          println(m.group(1))
```

I am getting output, but i want to migrate this scala using scala.util.matching library.
How to implement this in simply?

This code is working with java utils.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, you may use an `unanchored` regex within a `match` block to get just the captured part:

```
val s = "http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/?rapidView=416&projectKey=DSCI&view=detail&"
val pattern ="""[?&]rapidView=(\d+)""".r.unanchored
val res = s match { 
    case pattern(rapidView) => rapidView
    case _ => ""
}
println(res)
// => 416
```

See the [Scala demo](http://ideone.com/zpX9Ai)

**Details**:

- `"""[?&]rapidView=(\d+)""".r.unanchored` - the triple quoted string literal allows using single backslashes with regex escapes, and the `.unanchored` property makes the regex match *partially*, not the entire string
- `pattern(rapidView)`  gets the 1 or more digits part (captured with `(\d+)`) if a pattern finds a partial match
- `case _ => ""` will return an empty string upon no match.

Comment: Thanks alot Wiktor for your quick repsonse

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily with Scala:

```
scala> val url = "http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/?rapidView=416&projectKey=DSCI&view=detail&"
url: String = http://localhost:8080/bladdey/shop/?rapidView=416&projectKey=DSCI&view=detail&

scala> url.split("rapidView=").tail.head.split("&").head
res0: String = 416
```

You can also extend it by parameterize the search word:

```
scala> def searchParam(sp: String) = sp + "="
searchParam: (sp: String)String

scala> val sw = "rapidView"                                                                                                                                      
sw: String = rapidView
```

And just search with the parameter name

```
scala> url.split(searchParam(sw)).tail.head.split("&").head
res1: String = 416  

scala> val sw2 = "projectKey"                                                                                                                                    
sw2: String = projectKey                                                                                                                                         

scala> url.split(searchParam(sw2)).tail.head.split("&").head
res2: String = DSCI
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks Robert. Appreciate you.